# issues with Raphaël and removing objects within svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js, raphael

if you open the code pen there is a fire button. it will launch a bunch of ellipses and then when it hits it will cause a burst. if you look the ellipses    ,which there are two sets of, they are still there. I have tried using the below

```
d3.selectAll("ellipse").remove()
$("ellipse").remove()
$("ellipse").each(function(){this.remove()})
```

http://codepen.io/daniel667/pen/QwMWrm

the code pen above will help show what im talking about the second fire button to the far right is what ive been trying to use to kill the ellipses  so I don't wait for the animation the functions at the very bottom.

Comment: Not quite sure why you are using d3..but I'd probably just store them in a Raph set and then iterative over the set and remove them (or hide them and reuse later), something like http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogezEW as an example. Just extra unrelated thought. It also seems a bit slow, so it would be worth looking at something like velocity.js (the glow possibly also slows it a bit, so may be alternatives as well).

Comment: I was just using d3 to try to do the same task to see if I could get it to work. tried to explore all paths prior to asking.

Comment: ill investigate the glow. I was thinking of using velocity.js. maybe ill explore that. Is there a reason you didn't use your solution as the answer?

Comment: I'll set it as an answer if you think its helpful, I wasn't sure if there was something I was missing like you needed d3 use for some reason.

Comment: no I was just using d3 as an attempt to do the same thing. so yes please go ahead and set it as an answer. youre right the glow did seem to slow things down a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a Raphael set, or an array and store the elemets in that, so you can reference them later to remove. If they will be used repeatedly, it may be worth not removing them, but just hiding them rather than recreating each time.

```
var mySet;
...
mySet = paper.set();
mySet.push( circi );

....
function throwss() {
  mySet.forEach( function( el ) { el.remove(); });
}
```

Example: [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogezEW)

For speed, you may also want to look into Velocity.js, also be aware for animation filters can be quite resource heavy.

Comment: http://s.codepen.io/daniel667/debug/QwMWrm?  in debug mode it throws an error I cant see the issue but I have bad eyes mind taking a look,

Comment: animate({along :1} 3000, "linear"...add a comma after the }

Comment: you deserve to win the internet.